# SQL Query to Combine Dates

Tags: sql, string, datetime, teradata

I have a data set that has dates like this:

```
MM    DD    YY
2     8     10
3     9     11
4     10    12
```

I'm trying to write a query that displays the dates in one single column as MM/DD/YY

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: What are the data types of those columns and what data type should be the result?

Comment: Does your year really not have a century?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind the data format, you can concatenate them.

```
select MM || '/' || 'DD' || '/' || YY DATE_COL from T
```

you can also convert it to date

```
select to_Date(MM || '/' || 'DD' || '/' || YY, 'MM/DD/YY') DATE_COL from T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do below, assuming your year is in the 21st century.

```
 select to_Date(lpad(MM,2,'0')|| '/' ||lpad(DD,2,'0')|| '/20' ||lpad(YY,2,'0'),'MM/DD/YYYY') as Date_field 
 from my_Table;
```

Here is a demo in Oracle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1ba6814d793f2b8b269611e348540f6c. This would work in Teradata as well.

Comment: There's no need to include the slashes, just `MM|DD|'20'YY, 'MMDDYYYY'`.

Answer (score 0):

Teradata actually stores dates as integers, as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/SYAOV9GNqYNbGsM8RUiEMQ):

> Teradata Database stores each `DATE` value as a four-byte integer using the following formula: `(year - 1900) * 10000 + (month * 100) + day`.

If you want to generate a result of `date` datatype from your numbers, you can just do:

```
cast((yy + 100) * 10000 + mm * 100 + dd as date)
```

On the other hand, if you just want a string in format `mm/dd/yy`, it is probably simpler to use string functions; we just need to pad the 1-digit values with `0`:

```
lpad(mm, 2, '0') || '/' || lpad(dd, 2, '0') || '/' || lpad(yy, 2, '0')
```